# What does triangle/circle sign mean in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

[PyCharm window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX0Lt.png)

Before it was a circle now it is a triangle. What does it stand for?

Comment: Probably a pending Git commit that is not yet pushed.

Comment: Is there some place where I can read what other sign there can be and what they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of your PyCharm screen there's a toolbar with info that corresponds to what you see in the `Project` window. This should help you explain what these icons mean.

For example:

If the branch is up-to-date and there are no new changes you'll see this:

[image]

If there are some and haven't been committed you will see this:

[image]

You can click on this widget to get a context menu:

[image]

Also, I highly recommend exploring the [Repository and Incoming Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/version-control-tool-window-repository-and-incoming-tabs.html).

To read more about PyCharm's common symbols, see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html#common-icons).